# Integrating work done by vectors, what are the bounds?

Tags: calculus, vectors

***Find the work done when the force
̰ = (−)̰+ (4^2)̰+ (2^2)̰ 
  moves its point of application along the straight line joining  (0,0,0) to  (5,2,−1)***

In the answers it saids
*"Also, (0,0,0) corresponds to  = 0, whilst (5,2, −1) corresponds to  = 1."*

So I understand you must find the integral and such, but I don't understand how the  bounds equal b=1 and a=0 from the points A and B, how did it get narrowed down to 1 and 0 from each point?

Another question I found that is similar

Determine a tangent vector and
the equation of the tangent line to the space curve

r(t) = (t)i+ (t^2)j+ (t^3)k

at the point (2, 4, 8)

Differentiating once with respect to t gives
r˙(t) = i+(2t)j+(3t^2)k

so that a tangent vector at (2, 4, 8), **where t = 2**, is i+4j+12k.

How was is it concluded that t=2?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given point $A$ and $B$, a common way of parametrization of the straight line connecting $A$ and $B$ is $r(t)=(1-t)A+tB$.

For this particular choice of parametrization, we can easily see that $r(0)=A$ adn $r(1)=B$.

For your second question, the parametrization has been chosen to be $(t, t^2, t^3)$.

To find the corresponding $t$ that gives point $(2,4,8)$. We solve for

$$(t,t^2, t^3)=(2,4,8)$$

and we can see from the first component that $t=2$. The other two components hold as well.